# Flask: How to show different data from PostgreSQL DB to different users by their login username?

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask

I am trying to show data from a table from the database by a user name entered by a user.
That means a user goes through an ID and gets a page with his data from a table.
I can display a username but can not display other columns that belong to the same user.
Example  PostgreSQL database:
[image]

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect, url_for
import psycopg2

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'mykey123'

@app.route("/", methods = ["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    r = ""
    msg = ""
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        username = request.form["username"]
        password = request.form["password"]
        conn =psycopg2.connect(host="****", port = 5432, database="***", user="****", password="*****")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM public.person WHERE username = '"+username+"' and password = '"+password+"' ")
        r = c.fetchall()
        for i in r:
            if (username == i[1] and password == i[2]):
                session["logedin"] = True
                session["username"] = username
                return redirect(url_for("about"))
            else:
                msg = "Please enter valid username and password"
    return render_template("login.html", msg=msg)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
    return render_template("about.html")

@app.route("/logout")
def logout():
    session.clear()
    return redirect(url_for("login"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><title>Login</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login Page</h1>
<form action="" method=post>
    <h2>Username</h2>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <br>
    <h2>Password</h2>
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

in about.html I set {{session.username}} to display the incoming username.

about.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>.<title>About Page</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h1>{{session.username}}</h1>
<h1><a href="/logout">Logout</a></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

How can I display additional data from a table that belongs to the same user: id, email, gender, country ??

Comment: Basically, you have to do a database query in the view of the respective html page and and return as a context dictionary.

Comment: You should have only one result to your sql query in the login route. You should use fetchone(). There is no need to do a loop there. The about route should do a query to get the fields you need to show your user using the username you put in the session.

Comment: This: username = '"+username+"' is an accident waiting to happen, see [Bobby Tables](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/Little_Bobby_Tables). This [SQL parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) is what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

The "r" variable which you are using is a list of all the rows in the database in a tuple form, so you can iterate through it on the html and print it.
Go through this link, you will get a better understanding,
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-python-querying-data/

Comment: username and password come from request.form after user login. 
How can I move them to "/about"  and use them as variables in SQL query to retrieve additional data for the same user?